# The mean square error

Tags: statistics

[image]

My turn :-

$MSE(T) = Var(T) + bias^2(T)$

$Var(T) = E(T^2) -E(T) = \frac{5}{7}R^2 - \frac{25}{36}R^2 = \frac{5}{252} R^2 $

Now i do not know how can i find $bias(T)$

I know that

$bias(T) = E(T) -T $

But what should I replace $T$ with ?

Comment: Do not post pictures of text as they are not searchable.

Comment: The text is so long to be written @David G.Stork

Comment: Irrelevant.  You must show that *you* have done some work too.  Anyway, it *isn't* very long at all.  Just look at the hundreds of posted questions that are longer....  And this sure looks like a homework problem, which is explicitly prohibited here.

Comment: Even if it is a homework , i have showed some work as much as i could , so what the problem with that ? @David G.Stork

Comment: You are estimating $R$, so bias(T) is $E(T-R)=E(T)-R$. Be careful that $Var(T)=E(T^2)-[E(T)]^2$. And please consider typing out the relevant parts of the question.

Comment: "as much as I could"???  Really?  Copied a basic equation from a textbook, and you couldn't even type the question?!  Regardless, this is not a site for our doing your homework for you, regardless how much or little you've "done."  This is patently unfair to other students in your class who don't ask for others to help (or *do*) their homework for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, the question already gives you the density of the statistic $T$, so all you have to do is compute the first two moments.  For $k > 0$, we have

$$\operatorname{E}[T^k] = \int_{t=0}^R t^k f_T(t) \, dt = \int_{t=0}^R t^k \frac{5t^4}{R^5} \, dt = \frac{5}{R^5} \left[\frac{t^{5+k}}{5+k}\right]_{k=0}^R = \frac{5R^k}{(5+k)}.$$

Setting $k = 1$ and $k = 2$ gives $$\operatorname{E}[T] = \frac{5}{6}R, \quad \operatorname{E}[T^2] = \frac{5}{7}R^2.$$

Next, recall that the bias of an estimator $w(\theta)$ of $\theta$ is $\operatorname{E}[w(\theta) - \theta]$.  Specifically, since the statistic $T$ is intended to estimate $R$, we have
$$\operatorname{Bias}[T] = \operatorname{E}[T - R] = \operatorname{E}[T] - R = -\frac{R}{6}.$$
You have misunderstood what bias means, which is why you got confused trying to calculate it.

Comment: Thank you so much @heropup